# Why can't I access a variable by name declared in cell edit template in the code behind?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid, autocompletebox

I have a silverlight gird. One of the columns I use AutoCompleteBox as cell edit template. I declare it as follows

```
<c1:Column.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <sdk:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="TestField" Text="{Binding ReferencePath,Mode=TwoWay}"                                       Populating="tester_Populating" MinimumPrefixLength="0" IsDropDownOpen="True" LostFocus="tester_LostFocus"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </c1:Column.CellEditingTemplate>
```

When I tried to access TestField in the code behind, it is not available. Why is this variable not accessible in the code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the following link,

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/200237/467179.aspx